# How to change LinearLayout orientation many times in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-orientation

I have problems with changing an orientation of LinearLayout many times in Android because in my scenario, I have a line number for changing orientation. In the other hand if numbers will be changing layouts orientation must be changed, but it doesn't work
My code:

```
  first_line=w.getW_line();                                                                             


  if(first_line>second_line){                                                                           
      linearLayout_text.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);                                          
      second_line=first_line;                                                                           
  }                                                                                                     
  else if((first_line==second_line) ) {                                                                 

      linearLayout_text.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);                                        
  }                                                                                                     
  else {                                                                                                
      linearLayout_text.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);                                        
  }                                                                                                     



  TextView textView=new TextView(getActivity());                                                        

  textView.setText(w.getW_text());                                                                      
  textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,        
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                                                     
  textView.setTag(w.getW_id());                                                                         
  linearLayout_text.addView(textView);
```

Changing orientation didn't work. How to resolve this problem?
Is it supported to change orientation in LinearLayout in Android?

Comment: try  layout.invalidate() after change the orientation

Comment: How many textviews do you have?

Comment: i create dynamically all textViews\

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you're asking in your question but it seems like you want to rotate your textview are trying to rotate the linearLayout that contains the textview... If you just want to rotate the text, you can try

```
textview.setRotation(float);
```

where the float is just by how many degrees you want to rotate your object in clockwise direction.

Comment: The as faraz khonsari pointed it out, you might want to try to linearLayout.invalidate() to 'refresh' your layout

Comment: can i use frameLayout for resolving problem ?

Comment: My guess is you'll probably run into the same problems. Invalidate() should be called every time you change the orientation of a layout, you should put it in the update() function, however that might require a loop(through a separate thread) or an event(such as onClick()) to trigger it.